# Remove leading and trailing whitespace from list of string in C#

Tags: c#

I have list of string and I want to trim leading and trailing whitespace.

It holds value like `"   Hi this "`, `"  computer  "` and so on.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do this?

```
List<string> aList = new List<string>();
```

Comment: add .`Trim()` to the end of each string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trim leading and trailing whitespace on each item by using a Linq selector:

```
var withoutWhitespace = aList.Select(item => item.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple with Linq:

```
var newList = aList.Select(s => s.Trim());
```

If you *need* a list just add `.ToList()` to the end. You could also overwrite the same list variable, or use a `for` loop to replace the strings in the list in-place:

```
for(int i=0; i < aList.Count; i++)
{
    aList[i] = aList[i].Trim();
}
```

Comment: You would need to add ToList if you want a list vs IEnumerable

Comment: You missed adding ToList() so LINQ wouldnt fire

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava presumably the new enumerable would be enumerated at some point or why trim anything at all.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Why create a new list if you don't need it? If all the OP is going to do is loop over the trimmed strings once there's no need to create a new list.

Comment: In a program it would. But looking at the question - I dont think OP has read about LINQ. But thats just my opinion.

Comment: My only nitpick here (and it's a *minor* one) is the variable name suggests that a new list is created.

Answer (score 2):

```
aList.Select(x=>x.TrimStart().TrimEnd()).ToList()
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Dragon Reborn use `Trim()` instead of `.TrimStart().TrimEnd()`?

Comment: @Amy Hahaha well... I'm a little mad.

Answer (score 1):

```
aList = aList.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Use ` when writing single line of code or ``` when adding a block of code

Comment: Agree - I missed it in the hurry to post an answer and win points :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, bellow is the simple answer:

```
var xList = aList.Select(x => x?.Trim('"').Trim()).ToList();
```

It will remove leading and trailing whitespace inside quotes.